# How should QuartzCore.framework imported in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, quartz-core, cglayer

I need QuartzCore.framework to add borderColor to a textfield, how?

Comment: `import QuartzCore` should do the trick...

Comment: @CodaFi Indeed it does. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

If you imported UIKit you don't need to import QuartzCore. Here is code

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```